# Deep Learning: is there any open-source library that can be integrated with Hadoop streaming and MapReduce?

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming, deep-learning

Google search popped out quite a few open source deep learning frameworks. Here is a collected list

```
Google TensorFlow
Theano
mxnet
keras
Pylearn2
Blocks
Lasagne
chainer
scikit-neuralnetwork
theano-lights
deepy
idlf
reinforce.js
opendeep
mxnet.js
CGT
Torch
Caffe
scikit-cuda
cuda4py
```

Which one can be implemented in a straight-forward way with Hadoop streaming and MapReduce?

Python is prefered, other languages can also be considered.

**EDIT:**

Currently I am mainly interested in Deep Reinforcement Learning and LSTM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deeplearning4j claims to be scalable on Hadoop and Spark:

http://deeplearning4j.org/

Comment: That's correct! Deeplearning4j works as a Hadoop job and integrates with Spark on the slave level to orchestrate host threads. It includes a couple variations of LSTMs, but it doesn't have reinforcement learning yet. (Contributors are welcome). Please join our Gitter chat here if you have questions for the DL4J creators: https://gitter.im/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j